# How to open a link which was parsed in a div?

Tags: php, javascript, html, parsing, html-parsing

My site parses a spanish dictionary and lets you search for more than one word at a time. If you look up "hola" you get the first div). Some words come up with suggestions, like "casa", instead of definitions like "hola":

[image]

And what i am looking for is this:

[image]

So, i would like to: when you click on the suggestions (like CASAR in the example I posted) to print the result in a div like HOLA. Here is the code used:

```
$words = array('word0','word-1');
    function url_decode($string){
    return urldecode(utf8_decode($string));
    }

    $baseUrl = 'http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=';

    $cssReplace = <<<EOT

    <style type="text/css">
    // I changed the style
    </style>
    </head>
 EOT;

 $resultIndex = 0;

foreach($words as $word) {
if(!isset($_REQUEST[$word]))
    continue;

$contents = file_get_contents($baseUrl . urldecode(utf8_decode($_REQUEST[$word])));

$contents = str_replace('</head>', $cssReplace, $contents);
$contents = preg_replace('/(search?[\d\w]+)/','http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search', $contents);


echo "<div style='
      //style
     ", (++$resultIndex) ,"'>", $contents,
        "</div>";
}
```

I have tried with: `$contents .= '<a href="">' . $word . '</a><br/>';` But it didn't work nor I know really where/how to use it.

Comment: First of all +1 purely because I love the concept. Secondly, maybe you should look into javascript or jQuery along with ajax for this kind of interactive UX.

Comment: @francisco.preller thanks francisco,but i am just starting programming ahaha. I don't know where to start from with this problem so I was looking forward to a direct response or maybe an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'll use jQuery for the example because it will be the easiest to get the job done specially if you are new to programming.

**NOTE: I DO NOT RECOMMEND USING JQUERY -BEFORE- LEARNING JAVASCRIPT -- DO IT AT YOUR OWN RISK, BUT AT LEAST COME BACK AND LEARN JAVASCRIPT LATER**

First, read up on how to download and install jquery [here](http://jquery.com).

Secondly, you will want something a little like this, let's pretend this is your markup.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- This output div will contain the output of whatever the MAIN
         word being displayed is, this is where HOLA would be from your first example -->
    <div id="output">

    </div>

    <!-- This is your suggestions box, assuming all anchor tags in here will result in
         a new word being displayed in output -->
    <div id="suggestions">

    </div>
</div>

<!-- Le javascript -->
<script>
    // Standard jQuery stuff, read about it on the jquery documentation
    $(function() {
        // The below line is a selector, it will select any anchor tag inside the div with 'suggestions' as identifier
        $('#suggestions a').click(function(e) {
            // First, stop the link going anywhere
            e.preventDefault();

            // Secondly, we want to replace the content from output with new content, we will use AJAX here
            // which you should also read about, basically we set a php page, and send a request to it
            // and display the result without refreshing your page
            $.ajax({
                url: 'phppage.php',
                data: { word: 'casar' },
                success: function(output) {
                    // This code here will replace the contents of the output div with the output we brought back from your php page
                    $('#output').html(output);
                }
            })
        });
    })
</script>
```

Hopefully the comments will shed some light, you need to then set up your php script which will be sent a GET request. (for example, http://some.address.com/phppage.php/?word=casar)

Then you just echo out the output from PHP

```
<?php

    $word = $_GET['word'];
    // Connect to some database, get the definitions, and store the results
    $result = someDatabaseFunctionThatDoesSomething($word);
    echo $result;
?>
```

Hope this helps, I expect you have a lot of reading to do!

Comment: outstanding explanation Francisco, but the problem is not specifically with the word "casa", but with any word that may have suggestions.

Comment: in fact, the code i posted works: tri any words in spanish here:    But the only problem is with words like "casa", do you really think I have to start from scratch with your code from above?

Comment: Glad you got it working, in a real world situation as opposed to my example, you would replace the word 'casa' with the text of the anchor tag or something. For example $("suggestions a").text() instead of the static value 'casa' within ajax.

Comment: sorry if you misunderstood but i didnt got it working. I believe there is soemthing to add in my code, not to tackle the problem in another way like you kindly posted above. Here is what i am saying, click on casa: http://verbum.xtrweb.com/verbumpost.php?word0=hola&word-1=casa